# DataInputStream with sockets... missing bytes?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, byte

In my project, I'm using a `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` to send and receive bytes using sockets with threads.

**Client**

```
public void run(){
    while(isRunning) {//which is true upon connection of the socket to the server
         if(scanner.hasNext()){ // I use a scanner to test the program
             dos = new DataOutputStream(new OutputStream(socket.getOutputStream));

             byte[] toServer = scanner.next().getBytes();
             dos.writeInt(toServer.length);
             dos.write(toServer);
         } 
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
public void run(){
    while(isRunning){
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
              dis = new DataInputStream(new InputStream(socket.getInputStream));    
              int arrLength = dis.readInt();

              byte[] fromClient = new byte[arrLength];
              dis.read(fromClient, 0, fromClient.length);
              System.out.println("Your string is: " + new String(fromClient));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I print out the `new String(fromClient)` on the server side, the first character of the word/sentence is always missing. When I enter the word `"Test"` on the client, the server prints out `"est"`. But when I enter `" Test"` (with a space at the beginning), the server prints out `"Test"`. I don't understand what's wrong? Is there a problem with my byte conversion?

Comment: `dos.writeInt(toServer)` must be a typo since it would not compile.

Comment: and also, the `InputStream`/`OutputStream` typo in client/server

Comment: Yup, they are typos... sorry.

Comment: First, should be able to use `dis.read(fromClient)` although this shouldn't fix the issue

Comment: Also, `socket.getInputStream()` returns an `InputStream` so there is no point in doing `new InputStream`.

Comment: Again, sorry for the typos. I don't have access to the code right now since it is at work and I'm at home right now thinking how to solve this.

@JohnB: I tried using dis.read(fromClient) as well, same thing happened.

Comment: Have you verified that the size is being read correctly? Since `read` can return fewer bytes than length it is possible your array is not fully populated.

Comment: Hmm.. I just assumed that `writeInt(toServer.length)` gets the total number of bytes from that array and `readInt` retrieves the number that was written using `writeInt(toServer.length)`. Also, what can make `read()` return fewer bytes than the specified length?

Comment: I've just did a quick test according to your code, no problem found, data are received as expected on the server side. What's the delimiter pattern of your scanner?

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: think I set it to "\n".

Comment: Also, you can't do `new InputStream()` (and OS).  They are abstract so it won't compile.  Did you mean for that to be buffered or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works for me.  Given the typos in the post, I suspect that this is not the actual code that is running but rather an approximation and that this a bug in the real code.  Here's some things to look for:

- If you have a `dis.readByte();` after the `readInt()` call, that obviously will cut off the lead character.  Make sure that your writes and reads are completely symmetric.  Also make sure that your stream chain is symmetric.
- If you are getting your stream from another class, make sure that it is not doing any read methods itself.
- The current post is doing a `new InputStream()` (and `OutputStream`) which won't compile since they are abstract.  If there is buffering in there you will need to make sure that you `dos.flush();`.  That would cause a hang however and not partial input.

---

```
String file = "/tmp/x";
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

String inputString = "Test";
byte[] toServer = inputString.getBytes();
dos.writeInt(toServer.length);
dos.write(toServer);

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
int arrLength = dis.readInt();

byte[] fromClient = new byte[arrLength];
dis.read(fromClient, 0, fromClient.length);
// works fine for me
assertEquals(inputString, new String(fromClient));
```

Comment: Will try this once I get back to work! Thanks!

EDIT: In your example, you used FileOutputStream instead of getting the socket's InputStream/OutputStream... would that matter?

Comment: Yeah it certainly might @user979023.   It was more a demonstration that I don't think that the code you've posted is wrong -- aside from the typos.

Comment: Here's a working socket client/server @user979023.  Seems to work fine: http://pastebin.com/hqnfd7Pg

Comment: I seriously hate maintaining code that's done by another person... sigh... Anyways, @Gray, thank you so much for your help. Your sample codes have worked for me. +10000000!

Comment: @user979023 This code assumes that read() fills the buffer. You can't assume that: see the Javadoc. You need to use readFully().

Answer (score 0):

You should use readFully() rather than read(), and you shouldn't keep reconstructing the streams for every read or write. Use the same streams for the life of the socket. Also what is the scanner attached to? If it's attached to the socket it will consume data from it.

Comment: I tried using `readFully()` but somehow the program just stops working... even on debug mode.

Comment: @user979023 So what is the scanner attached to again?